# Algebra Books containing Questions and Solutions Only

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book in abstract algebra which covers:

- Fields
- Rings
- Jordan Form
- Factor Rings

I already have a book to read the theory. Unfortunately it's very abstract with almost no examples.

Is there a book which contains **examples and solutions** to them only?

Comment: There is **Algebra through Practice** in six volumes.

Comment: @user296113 thanks, do they have worked solutions? Might be what I need

Comment: @GRS Yes, because the full name is Algebra Through Practice: A Collection of Problems in Algebra *with Solutions*.